# Download occurs at my custom gin-golang based REST server side, but not occurring at client side

Tags: rest, go, curl, go-gin

I am creating an HTTP REST server in golang using gin-gonic

My code is:

```
func main() {

    var port string
    if len(os.Args) == 1 {
        port = "8080"
    } else {
        port = os.Args[1]
    }

    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/:a/*b", func(c *gin.Context) {
        
        // My custom code to get "download" reader from some third party cloud storage.
        
        // Create the file at the server side
        out, err := os.Create(b)
        if err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error in file creation at server side\n")
            return
        }
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "File created at server side\n")

        _, err = io.Copy(out, download)
        if err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Some error occured while downloading the object\n")
            return
        }

        // Close the file at the server side
        err = out.Close()
        if err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Some error occured while closing the file at server side\n")
        }
        
        // Download the file from server side at client side
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Downloading the file at client side\n")
        c.FileAttachment(objectPath, objectPath)
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "\nFile downlaoded at the client side successfully\n")
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Object downloaded successfully\n")

    })

    // Listen and serve 
    router.Run(":"+port)    
}
```

When I run the curl command at the client side command prompt, it downloaded that file on my REST server, but did not download on my client side. However, the [gin-gonic godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin) says that:

> **func (*Context) File**
> `func (c *Context) File(filepath string)`
> File writes the specified file into the body stream in a efficient way.
> **func (*Context) FileAttachment**
> `func (c *Context) FileAttachment(filepath, filename string)`
> FileAttachment writes the specified file into the body stream in an efficient way On the client side, the file will typically be downloaded with the given filename
> **func (*Context) FileFromFS**
> `func (c *Context) FileFromFS(filepath string, fs http.FileSystem)`
> FileFromFS writes the specified file from http.FileSystem into the body stream in an efficient way.

But, on close observation from my command prompt output, it printed the content of the txt file, which I need to save on my client side

So, I would like to stream that download from that 3rd party storage to the client side command prompt or browser, via my custom REST API server.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**  I tried to write `Content-Disposition` & `Content-Type` headers to response as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {

    var port string
    if len(os.Args) == 1 {
        port = "8080"
    } else {
        port = os.Args[1]
    }

    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/:a/*b", func(c *gin.Context) {
        
        param_a := c.Param("a")
        param_b := c.Param("b")
        
        reqToken := c.GetHeader("my_custom_key")

        // My custom code to get "download" reader from some third party cloud storage.

        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Downloading the object\n")


        c.Writer.Header().Add("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=%", param_b))
        c.Writer.Header().Add("Content-Type", c.GetHeader("Content-Type"))
        c.File(param_b)


        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Object downloaded successfully\n")

        err = download.Close()
        if err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error in closing the download of the object\n")
            return
        }
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "Object downloaded completed & closed successfully\n")

    })

    // Listen and serve 
    router.Run(":"+port)    
}
```

Now, it displays error, but also the success messages as follows, but the fill is still not downloaded at client side:

```
404 page not found
Object downloaded successfully
Object downloaded completed & closed successfully
```

Comment: Does gin support invoking `c.String` multiple times in a single context?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, the output at my client side command prompt displayed all these c.Strings indicating the successful connection to 3rd party cloud storage referred to by my REST server

Comment: And how does it write headers? Aren’t headers, by definition, supposed to be at the top of the response? Are the file attachment headers at the top in your command prompt?

Comment: @mkopriva The starting portion of the code is:  ```param_a := c.Param("a")
          param_b := c.Param("b")
  // some code
  
  reqToken := c.GetHeader("myCustomKey")```

Comment: and my curl command in cmd is: ```curl -H "myCustomKey: my_authorization_key_value" http://localhost:8082/directory1/hello.txt```

Comment: I'm talking about writing headers into the response, not reading them from the request. A file attachment *response* requires specific headers and I was just wondering how they are written to the top of the response if you've already sent a bunch of unrelated text.

Comment: Have updated the post with the updated code

Comment: What happens if you try just the `c.FileAttachment` you had before and no, **none at all**, `c.String` calls? What response does curl get then?

Comment: ... btw if `c.File(param_b)` returns 404 then that means that there is not file at `param_b`.

Comment: I tried c.FileAttachment also, but same "404" error. I removed all c.String calls, still same 404 error. Yes, the file is at 3rd party storage, not at my golang-gin based REST server. I actually want to somehow stream the download Reader (some kind of io.Reader) obtained from 3rd party storage to the client terminal/browser via my REST server code

Comment: If you have an `io.Reader` instance you should be able to upload its contents with [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) and [`c.Writer`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Writer) as the destination. Just make sure that before you invoke copy you set the appropriate headers.

Comment: I tried       c.Writer.Header().Add("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=%", param_b))
         c.Writer.Header().Add("Content-Type", c.GetHeader("Content-Type")) 
                io.Copy(c.Writer, download_reader),                                                                
it displays content of the file to downloaded in the terminal where I run curl command, but it does not save it to any file

Comment: Then tell your curl command to save the output. See `curl -h` to find out how.

Comment: And in the future, please avoid posting long snippets of code in comments, it makes them unreadable. If you need to share more code you should edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: Thanks, the file is getting downloaded from the curl command with "-O" option now. :) However, it does not download from the browser since no authorization header key's value is passed when I simply type URL from the browser. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't tell the browser what headers to send just by typing in a url. You either have to use ajax or you have to change "where" in the request you pass the key, i.e. instead of using headers you could use query parameters, however those are not secure, even with ssl I believe, so if the key you want to send is secret and should not be visible to anyone but the client and the server, then you should not use query parameters.

Comment: Sorry, one more query: Is it possible to display (using gin or golang only) a custom pop-up after URL is entered, something like "Please enter your authorization header key's value to continue", which takes that value string, saves it in a variable after click on OK, which I can set to authorization header

Comment: No, not with only gin & golang, for browser UI you need to use html and for functionality, like displaying a popup and then sending the input from that popup as a header, you need javascript coupled with that html.

Comment: Ok, thanks, how may I mark your answer as the solution? There does not seem to be any option in the comments

Comment: Comments can only be upvoted, they can't be selected as the accepted answer. You can write up your final solution as answer and accept it, you may need to wait some time before it can be accepted. You'll have my upvote.